# Empty argument - form for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords

I want to implement a reset password functionality so I have followed [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=asciicast), I receive the mail with the link to redirect to an edit password page but I get an error here.

**View**

```
<h1>Reset Password</h1>

<%= form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
      <ul>
        <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update Password" %></div>
<% end %>
```

The error is :`First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

I'm assuming that @user is empty, I'm new on RoR and I don't know why I get this error

**Password Controller**

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    render :layout => false
  end
  def create

    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to :connect, :notice => "An E-mail has been send"
  end
  def edit
    render :layout => false
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end
  def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password &crarr; 
      reset has expired."
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your def edit to

```
def edit
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  render :layout => false

end
```

Comment: I don't know why that make me an error but thank you. but I've a new error. On this line 'elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])' with forbidden attributes

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 or Rails 4?

Comment: I have posted it, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add

```
@user = User.new
```

to your new method.

you have also another error for your create method. there is no user creation.

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    render :layout => false
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    if @user.save
      # your code to render success
    else
      # your code to render error
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email) # add more
  end
end
```

Comment: But I don't want to create an User

Comment: oh ok. but you have these errors to. maybe you can use it anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to '@user.update_attributes(params[:user])' with forbidden attributes error.

Rails 4 has new feature known as [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).
Change your password controller to:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    render :layout => false
  end
  def create

    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to :connect, :notice => "An E-mail has been send"
  end
  def edit 
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    render :layout => false
  end
  def update
  @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
    redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password &crarr; 
      reset has expired."
  elsif @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end


  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email_id, :password)
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I already resolved this error, that was the solution